# Python exception because of invalid environment setup?

Tags: python, paramiko

Disclaimer: .net developer trying to setup python environment.

I have `.py` files trying to call the following line:

```
from paramiko import SSHClient, SSHConfig
```

However I get error saying

```
ImportError: No module named paramiko
```

I believe this is because I have missed to install something? I start python command prompt and type

```
import paramiko without any problem.
```

Anyone familiar with this issue? (Using `python 2.7.6`)

Edit: Python command prompt recieves and understands the command "import paramiko..." but my cygwin terminal does not. I believe cygwin has invalid python install path.

Comment: does the error is `ImportError: No module named paramiko`

Comment: will you please give more detail? It seems you have `paramiko` variable before `import` statement and its showing its not a `module` error.

Comment: have you installed the paramiko module?

Comment: @suhail exactly! It´s: ImportError: No module named paramiko

Comment: your filename does it happen to be paramiko?

Comment: @joojaa nope, test.py is the name

Comment: @user2963623 I have paramiko installed, what is paramiko module? Edit: yes I believe I have got that module I can type import paramiko in a python command prompt without error

Comment: How many versions of Python do you have on your system?

Comment: @Burhan Khalid Only one, however I have been uninstalling an 2.7.5 version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are getting `ImportError: No module named paramiko` please install it. If you already installed, please check path of the module and check same path exists in `PYTHONPATH` environment variable.

Comment: allright problem seems to be that my windows drive have gotten paramiko installed, so if I type this in python command prompt it works, (windows).
But in cygwin it does not understand I have the module.

Comment: I think to use windows module in `cygwin` you have to do some configuration. Or you can install `paramiko` again in `cygwin`. Please check https://github.com/0xdata/h2o/wiki/Installing-Python-inside-Cygwin

Comment: yes thats correct, at the moment I type in cygwin: which python, and it gives me incorrect directory, do you by chance know how to edit that path? So when I type "which python" it returns instead of /usr/bin/python something more like cygwin/c/Python27?

Comment: `export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:<paramico dir path>`

Comment: Thanks a lot! For the link, that ought to do it! I defenitley missed some packages there, however I believe you could point out for cygwin to use the windows installed python instead?

Comment: If its solve your problem, please select answer as your answer. Other might get benefit from your accepted answer.

Comment: Why are you using cygwin when you have Python installed on Windows? Unnecessarily complicating things.

Comment: @Lafada yes I will once I have downloaded the packages (slow internet), however Im doubtful, I believe I must get cygwin to use my windows installed python.

Comment: @Burhan Khalid, Well Im labing with a linux based hardware. So to get the communication going I believe cygwin is required to execute the code properly?